# Electrons in an electric circuit , its movement and power delivered

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, charge

Does an electrical appliance convert electrons into its respective work , I mean is electron being consumed by appliance (say bulb ) and then this mass gives us energy.

or the same number of electron , just revolve around the circuit, then from where does power comes from,

Comment: Please proofread your question for grammar, punctuation, and capitalization. Please edit the title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrons have charge and so when there is a potential difference across a circuit, this charge moves through it. In an incandescent light bulb, there is a high resistance, meaning that there are many atoms with which the charges collide, transferring some of their kinetic energy. No electrons are being "consumed" by the light bulb, i.e. the number of electrons in the circuit does not change. The ability of the charges to do work is because of a potential difference, which can be achieved through a number of means, e.g. using voltaic cells or electromagnetic induction.

To gain a better idea of why potential difference moves charges, consider two isolated point charges of opposite charges, one positive and one negative. If you pull the negative charge away from the positive one, you are doing work on it in the form of potential energy, as you are opposing the electric field of the positive charge. If you let go, the negative charge will convert this potential energy into kinetic energy, as it is attracted to the positive test charge. A potential difference across a circuit, albeit simplified, essentially does this – it brings electrons from a higher potential to a lower potential, converting potential energy into the kinetic energy in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Power comes mostly from chemical reactions (batteries or thermic power plants), gravitational potentials (hydroelectric plants), nuclear spontaneous decay (nuclear power plants), or wind turbines. And solar energy, that (except for the nuclear plants) are really the source behind the others.

Comment: Yes , that's it , but what within the appliance

Comment: @user252460 Most appliances are connected to a power outlet, which uses an alternating potential difference induced by electromagnetic induction of a spinning coil in a power station. The spinning of the coil is achieved by a number of processes, for instance steam.

Answer (score 0):

No, the electron is not consumed in the appliance and converted to energy. The electrons just go in a loop. This conversion of mass to energy only happens in nuclear power plants.

An electrical appliance draws power from the electric potential source in the circuit. More specifically, it takes the energy of the electric field inside the wire. This originated due to the potential difference between the ends of the circuit. So when we 'use up' a battery, the potential difference between the ends reduces to zero. Here the chemical energy inside the battery is converted to work.

Comment: There is no electric field inside a conductor

Comment: Then how do you think electrons move inside the circuit?

Comment: Ya that's the problems , in intermediate level we have proved the expression for current using electric field , but there is no field inside conductor

Comment: Physics stays the same at all levels of study. There **needs** to be an electric field in a conductor for current to flow through it.  A simple google search will tell you this, get your basics right.

Answer (score -1):

Think of the electrons in a metallic circuit as being like the links in the drive chain of a bicycle. The motion of the chain delivers energy from the pedals to the rear wheel, but the links in the chain are not "consumed." The links travel in a circuit. After they have delivered energy, they go back to the pedals and acquire more energy.

Comment: Nice ans, but it's just an analogy

Comment: @user252460, OK, but how does it fail to answer your question? You asked, "is electron being consumed...?" No. They are not consumed. Just like how the links in a bicycle chain are not consumed. You asked, "do the same electrons just revolve around the circuit?" Yes. (If it's a D.C. circuit, A.C. is more complicated\*) they go 'round and 'round, just like the links on a bicycle chain.

Comment: \* One possible analogy for A.C.; You could construct a gearbox for a bicycle with a ratchet mechanism that would drive the rear wheel forward when the rider turns the pedals in _either_ direction. There's no practical use for that on a bicycle, but you _could_ make it work. So, imagine a rider who propels the bike forward by alternately pushing the pedals one way and the other. Any given chain link then would only ever "jiggle" back and forth without ever progressing around the loop. That's more or less what the electrons in an A.C. circuit do.